# how to re-calculate variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function scrollContent(){
    var div = $('#scrolling-content'),
                 ul = $('ul.image'),
                 // unordered list's left margin
                 ulPadding = 0;

    //Get menu width
    var divWidth = div.width();

    //Remove scrollbars
    div.css({overflow: 'hidden'});

    //Find last image container
    var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');

    //When user move mouse over menu
    div.mousemove(function(e){

    //As images are loaded ul width increases,
    //so we recalculate it each time
    var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;   
    var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;
      div.scrollLeft(left);
    });     
}
```

This is how I scroll my image list. The problem is that `#scrolling-content` element's size is dynamic. It changes on window resize. Here;

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        $("#scrolling-content").css("width",$(window).width() + "px");
        $("#scrolling-content").css("height",($(window).height()-400) + "px");
});
```

So it has to recalculate the left value when user changes windows size. How sould I change script to do that? Recalling `scrollContent()` function with `window.resize` function is a noob solution I guess. And it creates conflict for IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the width on resize and make your function call the variable like so. This method turns your function into a js object and the window update resets the width var inside that object. Course now you call the function like this: scrollContent.scroll();

```
var scrollContent = {
        width: 0,
        scroll:function(){
            var div = $('#scrolling-content'),
                     ul = $('ul.image'),
                     // unordered list's left margin
                     ulPadding = 0;

            //Get menu width
            scrollContent.width = div.width();

            //Remove scrollbars
            div.css({overflow: 'hidden'});

            //Find last image container
            var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');

            //When user move mouse over menu
            div.mousemove(function(e){

            //As images are loaded ul width increases,
            //so we recalculate it each time
            var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-scrollContent.width) / scrollContent.width;
              div.scrollLeft(left);
            });
        }  
    };

$(window).resize(function() {
        $("#scrolling-content").css("width",$(window).width() + "px");
        $("#scrolling-content").css("height",($(window).height()-400) + "px");
        scrollContent.width = $(window).width();
});
```

You can also just declare a standard js var and use that to keep things simple. I just prefer working with js objects to eliminate possible var interference.

Comment: Ok,done.your code is working after declaring ulWidth var.Thanks a lot,appreciated.